# How would I go about rigging this?

Tags: rigging

Recently, I began goofing around in Blender and came up with this

[image]

Now, I am a beginner and I wanted to rig him to use in unity, and I've been following several tutorials on how to rig characters in general. But the problem is a lot of the time, I end up getting stretching or some pieces of the robot won't follow the other parts, such as the fingers.

I have succumbed to frustration and have decided to put aside my stubbornness to come here and ask for advice.

Comment: Here are a few nice tips, scroll down to the message with the videos:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?248085-Rigging-a-ROBOT

Answer (score 1):

First enable the Rigify Addon in *Menu: File / User Preferences*

[image]

Now you can add the whole human rig to your scene in *Object Mode* <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

In *Edit Mode* align all bones with your model. When done parent the model to the rig <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> (With Automatic Weights).

[image]

And create the Meta-Rig.

[image]

After that you can create Actions and arrange them in the NLA editor. Importing to Unity is best done by *Import New Asset* from the *Asset Menu*.

A more detailed description with removal of unneeded bones is available in the Unity documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlenderAndRigify.html

[image]

If you don't want to animate a humanoid then chose *Animation Type: Generic*  in the import settings of the rig:

[image]